# SQL database - Table for interchangeable (alternative) material

Tags: sql

I have a small problem with one of my projects. In my database I have 3 tables:

```
 -materials [ID_material, material]
 -products [ID_product, product]
 -bill_of_materials [ID_product, ID_material, quantity]
```

Every product has a defined BOM. When manufacturing a product, sometimes you don't have the material specified in the BOM, but there is an alternative material that is interchangeable. I need to add one another table to my database, where I can specify what materials are interchangeable. How should I design this table?

An example:

```
 We have 4 different materials: A, B, C, D
 We have a product: myProduct
 And we have a bill of material for myProduct: 1 unit of A + 2 units of B
```

Materials B, C and D are not the same, but have same characteristics (a capacitor with same specs, but manufactured by different manufacturers - each must have a different ID in my database).
In my software I need to check stock of materials in BOM. If there is not enough stock, I need to check for alternative material (if it exists - not all materials have interchangeable counterparts). How would you design tables in a database for such example?

Comment: Is 'interchangable' a property of material? i.e. is a certain capacitor _always_ interchangeable, or must you always have the correct capacitor for certain products? (i.e.  board A can have any capacitor, board B _must_ have capacitor x) then simplest is to add another 'priority' column to your BOM table. However if the product doesn't care then it would make sense to have another bridging table, defining 'capacitor 10uF', which in turn points to a list of 10uF capacitors, with an a manufacturer column differentiating them

Answer (score 0):

It may depend upon the complexity of the problem, but why not have an Alternate Materials table that could be used to search for alternate materials if there were none available for the preferred material:

```
-alt_material[ID_Material, Alt_Material]
```

There may be other components to this including different quantities, preference of alternate materials (if multiple available) and if the alternate material is not always a suitable replacement (specific to products), which could add to the complexity of the problem:

```
-alt_material[ID_Product, ID_Material, Alt_Material, Preference_ID, Qty]
```

Your system could then search for a list of alternate materials and search inventory to determine if suitable replacements exist.

Hope this helps!